# Neo4j - Get certain nodes and relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an application where nodes and relations are shown. After a result is shown, nodes and relations can be added through the gui. When the user is done, I would like to get all the data from the database again (because I don't have all data by this point in the front-end) based on the Neo4j id's of all nodes and links. The difficult part for me is that there are "floating" nodes that don't have a relation in the result of the gui (they will have relations in the database, but I don't want these). Worth mentioning is that on my relations, I have the start and end node id. I was thinking to start from there, but then I don't have these floating nodes.
Let's take a look at this poorly drawn example image: 
[image: Poorly drawn example]

As you can see:

- node 1 is linked (no direction) to node 2.
- node 2 is linked to node 3 (from 2 to 3)
- node 3 is linked to node 4 (from 3 to 4)
- node 3 is also linked to node 5 (no direction)
- node 6 is a floating node, without relations

Let's assume that:

- id(relation between 1 and 2) = 11
- id(relation between 2 and 3) = 12
- id(relation between 3 and 4) = 13
- id(relation between 3 and 5) = 14

Keeping in mind that behind the real data, there are way more relations between all these nodes, how can I recreate this very image again via Neo4j? I have tried doing something like:

```
match path=(n)-[rels*]-(m)
where id(n) in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
and all(rel in rels where id in [11, 12, 13, 14])
and id(m) in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
return path
```

However, this doesn't work properly because of multiple reasons. Also, just matching on all the nodes doesn't get me the relations. Do I need to union multiple queries? Can this be done in 1 query? Do I need to write my own plugin?

I'm using Neo4j 3.3.5.

Comment: I want to get the data from the db exactly as it is displayed in the front-end. Imagine you have some nodes and relations through an action you do in the front-end, then you do some more and you get some new nodes extra in the front-end. All these nodes and relations, now I want to get them in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep a list of node IDs. Every relationship points to its 2 end nodes. Since you always want both end nodes, you get them for free using just the relationship ID list.

This query will return every single-relationship path from a relationship ID list. If you are using the neo4j Browser, its visualization should knit together these short paths and display your original full paths.

```
MATCH p=()-[r]-()
WHERE ID(r) IN [11, 12, 13, 14]
RETURN p
```

*By the way, all neo4j relationships have a direction. You may choose not to specify the direction when you create one (using `MERGE`) and/or query for one, but it still has a direction. And the neo4j Browser visualization will always show the direction.*

[UPDATED]

If you also want to include "floating" nodes that are not attached to a relationship in your relationship list, then you could just use a separate floating node ID list. For example:

```
MATCH p=()-[r]-()
WHERE ID(r) IN [11, 12, 13, 14]
RETURN p
UNION
MATCH p=(n)
WHERE ID(n) IN [6]
RETURN p
```

Comment: I see your point and it's totally valid. However, this does not take my "floating" nodes into account. I might keep this as a backup solution to get these relations with their nodes and then the remaining floating ones.

Comment: Oh, I did not understand that you also wanted some "floating" nodes. See my updated answer.